# Both train and test scores high. Could my model be overfitting?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

all. Currently I am working in a regressor to predict the median house value using 1990 census as a dataset (the same on Aurélien Géron used on his book).

My best result so far has been a score of ~0.96 for the training set and ~0.80 and for the test set with a bagging regressor. Here's how I had been doing:

```
precisao_treino = clf.score(dados_treino_feat,dados_treino_targ) #training score
precisao_valid = clf.score(dados_valid_feat,dados_valid_targ) #test score



(0.9698880465469455, 0.8087685894971024)
```

But here is where I get confused. That very high training score indicate that there is a potential overfit on my model. However, the test score is maintained a relative good score. So I don't know if my model is overfitting or if doing well at predicting. Could someone explain to me whether this a bad or good model?

---

Here's how my final dataset looks like, with one-hot-encoding:

```
['longitude',
 'latitude',
 'housing_median_age',
 'total_rooms',
 'total_bedrooms',
 'population',
 'households',
 'median_income',
 'median_house_value',
 '<1H OCEAN',
 'INLAND',
 'ISLAND',
 'NEAR BAY',
 'NEAR OCEAN']
```

My solution to removing outliers:

```
df = df[(np.abs(zscore(df)) < 6).all(axis=1)]
```

My model:

```
clf = ensemble.BaggingRegressor(n_estimators=20)
```

Answer (score 1):

Overfitting is nothing but when the model tries to *rot learn* the data given to it during the training process.

In such cases, the validation accuracy goes down as the model cannot interpret and classify unseen data.

> Reviewing the accuracies of the model, the validation accuracy soars to 0.8 which is quite good.

**The training accuracy is 0.96 which is a good sign and also it shows that model has generalised so well that it can classify all the data ( train and validation ) very well.**